# Use icon by replacing Bootstrap button class

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to Use icon for Printing. There is class name included in javascript like this

```
button:{className:"btn btn-info"}
```

How do I use icon in replace of that button class in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

like this: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)

```
<div class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></div>
```

Comment: Then we would need more context(code) in order to help you.

Comment: `$;b.fn.dataTable.Buttons||require("datatables.net-buttons")(a,b);return c(b,a,a.document)}:c(jQuery,window,document)})(function(c){var a=c.fn.dataTable;c.extend(!0,a.Buttons.defaults,{dom:{container:{className:"dt-buttons"},
button:{className:"btn btn-info"},collection:{tag:"ul",className:"dt-button-collection dropdown-menu",button:{tag:"li",className:"dt-button"},buttonLiner:{tag:"a",className:""}}}});a.ext.buttons.collection.text=function(a){return a.i18n("buttons.collection",'Collection <span class="caret"/>')};return a.Buttons}`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Button class (Add class, Remove class) using Javascript like this:

*To add class:*

```
document.getElementById("Element").classList.add('ClassName');
//Element   : change it to your button ID
//ClassName : change it to the class that you want Add it.
```

*To remove class:*

```
document.getElementById("Element").classList.remove('ClassName');
//Element   : change it to your button ID
//ClassName : change it to the class that you want Remove it.
```

or if you want it using JQuery:

*To add class:*

```
$('#Element').addClass('ClassName');
```

*To remove class:*

```
$('#Element').removeClass('ClassName');
```

*You can also make it in one line:*

```
$("#Element").removeClass("ClassOne").addClass("ClassTwo");
```

I hope it helps you, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't said to replace class to class. I want to replace class by icon.

Comment: (I want to replace class by icon). but icon also has a class, right?
i think we need more explain or jsfiddle demo if you can